# How to track network usage of my app on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, video, networking, mpmovieplayercontroller

My application play video from internet using MPMoviePlayer.

I should display: transferred data size and average data transfer speed (for current playing video). I cant get this information from MPMoviePlayer. So I decide to monitor network traffic of my app and use this information.

My question is:

How to track the network usage of my application? Can I determine how much data my application download from the net? How much time application does downloading of this data?

Answer (score 0):

Instruments can help you. There is a tool to collect network activity data.

Comment: I should display information in my app through the video playing. So, I need some API and classes to determine this information.

Comment: This post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring